# Session that never expires like on stackoverflow.com, unless the user clicks logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am building a asp.net mvc application. 
I want session to never expire, once the user login, unless the user clicks on logout.

Whats the best way of doing it?

I have used

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
```

and set createPersistentCookie to true, but still I get logged out after sometime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement sliding expiration. Leave the expiration time to some reasonable value - day, two, week max; renew the cookie on each request (simplest) or at certain intervals.

Comment: This will also work, and is probably better than using an expiry of 1 year

Answer (score 1):

FormsAuthentication cookies use the timeout value to determine expiration. The createPersistentCookie flag just tells the API to set an expires value, rather than allowing the cookie to expire when the browser is closed. To prevent expiration, increase the forms authentication timeout value in the web.config. That value is in minutes, so to force the cookie to last one year, use 525600.

Comment: Well, that will take a lot of memory on the server. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Huh? What will take a lot of memory? It's a single int value.

Comment: that is not going totake any memory on the server. cookie expiration is done through a imestamp on the client.

Comment: Ok then increasing forms authentication timeout value, should be fare enough. Which one is better sliding expiration or the above one, or it doesnt matter?

Comment: I'd go with Franci's sliding expiration suggestion. It's slightly more secure and desirable than a 1 year cookie, IMO

Comment: however, leaving the cookie there for a year is not a good idea. you want to be a bit mote aggressive with expiring inactive user sessions, especially if any of the user information might be sensitive.

Comment: Right. 1 week is probably long enough. If the site is heavily used, 2-3 days might even suffice.

Comment: Ok, then I will go with sliding expiration, do you know any good article where its explained, preferably with asp.net mvc?

Comment: just search for "asp.net forms authentication sliding expiration". there's bound to be tons of articles. :-)